# Kafka topic partition distributing evenly on disks

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster with 3 brokers (v2.3.0) and each broker has 2 disks attached. I added a new topic (heavyweight) and was surprised that even if the topic has 15 partitions, those weren't distributed evenly on the disks. Thus I got one disk that's almost empty and the other almost filled up. Is there any way to have Kafka evenly distribute data on its disks?

Comment: Kafka broker writes its data to the path defined in the config by **log.dirs**. So whichever disk is mounted on that path, will get filled up. You can use only one disk on a broker for kafka data.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, it's log.dirS. It's a comma-separated list where you can add your mounted disks. 

"log.dirs
The directories in which the log data is kept. If not set, the value in log.dir is used"

Comment: can you show the content/s of both your multiple paths using "ls -lh"

Comment: Not really. There are almost 30 topics with various partition size. Disk A has 115 folders,  50 folders are __consumer_offsets-XY (0-49), rest are the partitions. Disk B (newer one) has 6 partition folders.

Comment: I am sorry but I have not tried this so won't be able to provide you with a solution. During my research I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061426/how-to-spread-existing-kafka-topic-partitions-into-more-directories#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20kafka%20uses%20one,coma%20separated%20list%20of%20directories. It might be helpful.